why does this tumbling tetrahedra result depend on n?
In Section 15.4 of Jaynes' Probability Theory the Logic of Science (pdf here: http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf), he proposes following tumbling tetrahedra:

A regular tetrahedron with faces labeled e+ (positron), e− (electron), μ+ (muon), μ− (antimuon), is tossed repeatedly. A record is kept of the result of each toss, except that, whenever a record contains e+ followed immediately by e− (or e− by e+, or μ+ by μ−, or μ− by μ+), the particles annihilate each other, erasing that pair from the record. At some arbitrary point in the sequence, the player (who is ignorant of what has happened to date) calls for one more toss, and then is shown the final record x ∈ X , after which he must place bets on the truth of the proposition A ≡ ‘annihilation occurred at the final toss’. What probability P(A|x) should he assign?

At first sight, it seems to me that the probability P(A|x) would be 1/4, since whatever record x is, the probability of annihilation only depends on last 2 results, so probability should be 1/4, independent of the number of tosses n.
However, with some long derivation (Section 15.5), the author points out that P(A|x) should be approximately (n−y) / 2(n − 1) (when n is large, where y is length of record x).  Although I can follow his derivation, I do not understand why P(A|x) could depend on n.
The approach the author derives this result is by converting this problem to a random walk problem: every time, each step when an annihilation happens (with probability = 1/4), length of x decreases by 1, otherwise it increases by 1.  Then as above, let y be length of record x, he derives value for

From there, he got

Can anyone help explain why the result is dependent on n here?  Thanks!

Jaynes says that if you were to know that the number of tosses so far was $n$ and that  the length  of the record was $y$ then you would know there had been $\frac{n-y}{2}$ annihilations.
The first toss did not lead to an annihilation as there was no predecessor, so that leaves $\frac{n-y}{2}$ annihilations occurring in $n-1$ other tosses, i.e. an average of $\frac{n-y}{2(n-1)}$ annihilations per plausible toss, including the final toss.
So knowing $n$ and $y$ is informative about the impact of the final toss and thus they are present in (15.35).
This doesn't help so much if you do not know $n$ while $y$ is substantial, though for example knowing $y=0$ would persuade you the final toss must have led to an annihilation no matter what $n$ was (and also tells you $n$ was even).  But $\frac{n-0}{2(n-1)} \not = 1$ for $n>2$, and in fact $\frac{n-y}{2(n-1)}$ is not the exact probability that the final toss led to an annihilation even when $n$ and $y$ have the same parity; there is a distortion caused by the reflection of the random walk at $0$.

I feel like Jaynes is calculating P(A|y,n), not P(A|x). although y is length of x (meaning knowing x implies knowing y), but they do not seem to be the same, did I understand it incorrectly?

@username123: Jaynes has the final record as $x$ and its length as $y$.  Here, by exchangeability, $y$ (together with $n$) is sufficient and the details of $x$ add no useful information beyond its length.  This means $P(A \mid x, n)=P(A \mid y, n)$.  I must say that I am not a fan of Jaynes and his style or arguments, but that does not mean he is always wrong.

The player sees the record after the last toss, not the value of the last toss. If the last toss lead to an annihilation then the last toss will not be in the record. Also, the player sees $y$, not just $n$. If $y$ wasn't observed the answer would just be $1/4$, but when we know the total number of annihilations we have some information about $P(A)$.
Suppose $y=n$. We know there were no annihilations, so $P(A)$ must be zero. If  $y=n-2$ we know there was one annihilation, so we need to know the probability that it was the last toss. That's going to be something like $1/n$, and the formula gives $1/(n-1)$.  In the typical case, $y$ will be in the vicinity of $n/2$, since $1/4$ of rolls lead to annihilation and each one takes out two records.  The formula then gives about $1/4$ for $P(A)$, as expected.

Neither $\frac14$ nor $\frac{n-y}{2(n-1)}$ are exact, even if $y=\frac n2$ and they have the same parity.  As an example, $P(A \mid n=8, y=4) = \frac{21816}{4^8} \approx 0.3329$ while $\frac{n-y}{2(n-1)} = \frac{4}{14} \approx 0.2857$ and $\frac14=0.25$.
